# Connecting to ESRI ArcSDE 10.2 for Oracle with ArcPy

Tags: oracle, arcgis, esri, arcpy

I had a Python script running ArcPy 10.0 connecting to SDE for Oracle through connection files.  Everything worked great but when ArcGIS (ArcPy) was upgraded to 10.2.1 I can't get the ArcPy functions to return any results.  I can connect to the database through the same connection file using ArcCatalog.  I get no errors when trying to run an ArcPy function against the same connection file but I still get no results.

For example:

arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

returns an empty list.

Any pointers for what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This turned out to be a mismatch between versions of ArcPy. ArcGIS Engine was installed after ArcGIS Desktop which installed a new 64 bit version of Python2.7/ArcPy.  64bit ArcPy does NOT work in this context and so was the reason why the behavior was strange.  I am not sure why this 64bit version would even be installed if it doesn't work correctly but I assume there must be a reason.  The take home here is to make sure you are using a 32bit version of ArcPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a mismatch between versions of ArcPy. ArcGIS Engine was installed after ArcGIS Desktop which installed a new 64 bit version of Python2.7/ArcPy.  64bit ArcPy does NOT work in this context and so was the reason why the behavior was strange.  I am not sure why this 64bit version would even be installed if it doesn't work correctly but I assume there must be a reason.  The take home here is to make sure you are using a 32bit version of ArcPy.

Comment: Somehow almost 5 years later using the 64-bit Python that comes with ArcGIS Server 10.6.1 gives me troubles too. I can run my scripts, but ... they don't terminate after finishing.